# Pack + AWS + Ansible + Windows are not WORK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, devops, packer

I want to make AMI file from packer and ansible.
I have tried many configuration, but I have still a problem of connection to the instance.
Here is my packer conf:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
        "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
        "region":         "us-east-1"
      },
  "builders": [
    {
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "access_key": "{{ user `aws_access_key` }}",
        "secret_key": "{{ user `aws_secret_key` }}",
        "region": "{{ user `region` }}",
        "instance_type": "t2.micro",
        "source_ami_filter": {
          "filters": {
            "virtualization-type": "hvm",
            "name": "*Windows_Server-2012-R2*English-64Bit-Base*",
            "root-device-type": "ebs"
          },
          "most_recent": true,
          "owners": "amazon"
        },
        "ami_name": "packer-demo-{{timestamp}}",
        "user_data_file": "userdata/windows-aws.txt",
        "communicator": "winrm",
        "winrm_username": "Administrator"
      }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "powershell",
    "inline": [
      "dir c:\\"
    ]
  },
  {
      "type":  "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "./win-playbook.yml",
      "extra_arguments": [
        "--connection", "packer", "-vvv",
        "--extra-vars", "ansible_shell_type=powershell ansible_shell_executable=None"
      ]
  }]
}
```

The User data script is activating winrm on the AWS instance:

```
<powershell>
winrm quickconfig -q
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow

net stop winrm
sc config winrm start=auto
net start winrm

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope LocalMachine
</powershell>
```

Here is win-playbook.yml file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - win_ping:
```

I do have the packer.py installed in the ~/.ansible/plugins/connection_plugins/ directory and configured in ~/.ansible.cfg:

```
root@ip-172-31-30-11:~/demo# grep connection_plugins /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
connection_plugins = /root/.ansible/plugins/connection_plugins
root@ip-172-31-30-11:~/demo# ll /root/.ansible/plugins/connection_plugins
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  2 16:58 ./
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 May  2 17:11 ../
-rwx--x--x 1 root root  511 May  2 16:53 packer.py*
```

and then this is output error:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with Ansible...
==> amazon-ebs: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook --extra-vars packer_build_name=amazon-ebs packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible962278842 /root/demo/win-playbook.yml -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key842946567 --connection packer -vvv --extra-vars ansible_shell_type=powershell ansible_shell_executable=None
    amazon-ebs: ansible-playbook 2.5.2
    amazon-ebs:   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
    amazon-ebs:   configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
    amazon-ebs:   ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
    amazon-ebs:   executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
    amazon-ebs:   python version = 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
    amazon-ebs: Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
    amazon-ebs: Parsed /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible962278842 inventory source with ini plugin
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAYBOOK: win-playbook.yml *****************************************************
    amazon-ebs: 1 plays in /root/demo/win-playbook.yml
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: task path: /root/demo/win-playbook.yml:2
    amazon-ebs: Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
    amazon-ebs: <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
    amazon-ebs: The full traceback is:
    amazon-ebs: Traceback (most recent call last):
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 138, in run
    amazon-ebs:     res = self._execute()
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 558, in _execute
    amazon-ebs:     result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py", line 46, in run
    amazon-ebs:     result = merge_hash(result, self._execute_module(task_vars=task_vars, wrap_async=wrap_async))
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 705, in _execute_module
    amazon-ebs:     self._make_tmp_path()
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 251, in _make_tmp_path
    amazon-ebs:     result = self._low_level_execute_command(cmd, sudoable=False)
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 902, in _low_level_execute_command
    amazon-ebs:     rc, stdout, stderr = self._connection.exec_command(cmd, in_data=in_data, sudoable=sudoable)
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py", line 976, in exec_command
    amazon-ebs:     use_tty = self.get_option('use_tty')
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/__init__.py", line 58, in get_option
    amazon-ebs:     option_value = C.config.get_config_value(option, plugin_type=get_plugin_class(self), plugin_name=self._load_name, variables=hostvars)
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 284, in get_config_value
    amazon-ebs:     value, _drop = self.get_config_value_and_origin(config, cfile=cfile, plugin_type=plugin_type, plugin_name=plugin_name, keys=keys, variables=variables)
    amazon-ebs:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/config/manager.py", line 304, in get_config_value_and_origin
    amazon-ebs:     defs = self._plugins[plugin_type][plugin_name]
    amazon-ebs: KeyError: 'connection'
    amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {
    amazon-ebs:     "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    amazon-ebs:     "stdout": ""
    amazon-ebs: }
    amazon-ebs:         to retry, use: --limit @/root/demo/win-playbook.retry
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

packer version: 1.2.3

ansible version: 2.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue is common for Ansible `2.5.x` and Packer. Adarobin commented on the packer issue https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5845. We ran into the same issue, tested the solution and it worked for us.

> I was hitting the KeyError: 'connection' issue with Ansible 2.5 on
>   Packer 1.2.2 with the AWS builder and I think I have discovered the
>   issue. It looks like Ansible now requires plugins to have a
>   documentation string. I copied the documentation string from the SSH
>   connection plugin (since that is what the packer plugin is based on)
>   made a few changes and my packer.py now looks like this.
>
> https://gist.github.com/adarobin/2f02b8b993936233e15d76f6cddb9e00